# How to increase CPU for Pro Tools in my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, logic

I have all my music DAWs such as Pro Tools and Logic Pro in my 2021 MacBook Pro, how can I increase CPU?

Comment: Have you looked at Activity Monitor to check your CPU usage? I would be very surprised if you are maxing the CPU of an M1 Pro with Logic. Also, how much RAM?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to upgrade the CPU in the 2021 MacBook Pro. You will need to purchase a bigger/better/newer MacBook Pro in order to get a faster CPU.